# Issue with the offline page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The text on the offline page has a poorly chosen color scheme as can be seen below.
[image]

Here the text is visible because it is selected.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has been fixed, it will be live after our next production build.